# Is there a term for raising in Hold’em while only looking at one of the hole cards?

Tags: texas-hold-em, terminology

Is there a term for raising while purposely only knowing one of your hole cards, not both?

Are there any notable players known to look at only one of their cards?

Comment: "Donking"? It's not a good thing.

Comment: "Gambling" . . . .

Answer (score 1):

I think Doyle Brunson did it once on video, definitely not his standard practice. Possible if youre SB/flatting or Button/raising any Ace, but if people notice you've only looked at one card, then your hand becomes more obvious.

I can't imagine any benefit coming from doing that unless you automatically salivate when you have AA, and are trying to keep yourself in the dark.

Sometimes i flat SB blind to give myself a more credible check-raising range, if the BB is particularly difficult villain.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call it handicapping yourself. There really is no reason to do it if people can't read you. You are essentially trying to bait your opponent by pretending you don't care about the outcome, which is silly. But hey, if you're already in your opponent's heads, then you can do anything.

Anyways, there shouldn't be a name for this. If there were, it would be convoluted.